# Is it possible to show widget for 3 seconds only in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code:

```
showArrow?  IconButton(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowCircleRight,color: Colors.white,), onPressed: (){

                                    setState(() {
                                      showArrow = !showArrow;

                                    });

                                  }):IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),onPressed: (){},),
```

At the very beginning showArrow value is true, so when I press the icon it updates the icon but I want it to update icon after 3 second and meanwhile show a loading gif at the same place in some other widget(like AssetImage). So is it possible to do so?

[image]

Before updating the Icon I want it to show loading gif at the same place for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIRST SOLUTION:
It's better if you have a state management for you widget. So first you will show the IconButton (first icon) and then when click on it you can set a timer for three seconds or wait for a future value and replace the IconButton (first icon) with CircularProgressIndicator.

When the timer has finished replace back the CircularProgressIndicator with IconButton (second icon)

SECOND SOLUTION:

```
  var showArrow = false;
  var showLoading = false;

  Widget myIconButton() {
if (!showLoading)
  return showArrow
      ? IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.white),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              showArrow = !showArrow;
              showLoading = !showLoading;
            });
            Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
              if (mounted)
                setState(() {
                  showLoading = !showLoading;
                });
            });
          })
      : IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
          onPressed: () {},
        );
else
  return SizedBox(
      width: 20, height: 20, child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the on pressed:

```
setState(() {
       showArrow = false;
        // Anything else you want
});
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((_) {
      setState(() {
       showArrow = true; //goes back to arrow Icon
        // Anything else you want
      });
```

And in the widget itself something like:

```
showArrow ? ArrowIcon() : LoadingIcon();
```

This way once the arrow is pressed the state is false and after 3 seconds true again

Comment: Hey, Actually I want to update my Icon as well. I don't want to show the same Icon again after 3 seconds.